# Subscribe already in the email content

Tags: google-schemas

I've subscribed via the link in the email. But the "google button" is still inviting me to subscribe. It is quite disturbing for the client. Is there a way to adapt the "google" button automatically into "subscription done" if people use the CTA in the email content ?

Check the picture it will be easier for you to understand my question

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Louisa are you the sender?

To my knowledge, there is no way to adapt the action button to automatically into a "subscription done" if people use the CTA from within the email.

However, you can use "expiring actions", so that the action button disappears after x amount of days. Basically, you would just add *startTime* and *endTime* attributes.

You can find an example here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/actions/declaring-actions#expiring_actions